# Order statistics of absolute value of bivariate normal distribution

Tags: distributions, probability, normal-distribution, order-statistics, probability-inequalities

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are bivariate normal and let $|X|_{(1)}$ and $|X|_{(2)}$ 
be the ordered version of their absolute value. I am interesting in finding the following probabilities or some bounds on it.
\begin{align*}
Pr(|X|_{(1)} < c_1, |X|_{(2)} < c_2)
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
Pr(|X_1| < c_1, |X|_{(1)} < c_2)
\end{align*}
Can anyone familier with this give some hint or some references? Thank you very much. 
Hanna

Answer (score 5):

For $c_1 < c_2$, the event $\left\{|X|_{(1)} < c_1, |X|_{(2)} < c_2\right\}$ is the union of the two events 
$$\begin{align}
A &= \left\{-c_1 < X_{1} < c_1, -c_2 < X_{2} < c_2\right\}\\
B &= \left\{-c_2 < X_{1} < c_2, -c_1 < X_{2} < c_1\right\}
\end{align}$$
whose intersection is the event 
$A \cap B =  \left\{-c_1 < X_{1} < c_1, -c_1 < X_{2} < c_1\right\}$. The probabilities
of all three events can be expressed in terms of the bivariate cumulative normal distribution function, and then we can use
$$P\left\{|X|_{(1)} < c_1, |X|_{(2)} < c_2\right\} = P(A\cup B) = P(A) +P(B) - PA\cap B).$$

For $c_1 > c_2$, the event $\left\{|X|_{(1)} < c_1, |X|_{(2)} < c_2\right\}$ is the same
as the event $A\cap B$.